# How to compute anomaly of a time series?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a time series of temperature data as:

```
ifile.txt
1921  25
1922  25.1
1923  24.2
1924  23.4
1925  24.4
1926  25.1
1927  23.6
1928  25.2
1929  23.9
1930  25.6
```

I would like to computed the anomaly for the period 1923-1929.

My algorithm to do it is:

```
1923  24.2 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1924  23.4 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1925  24.4 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1926  25.1 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1927  23.6 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1928  25.2 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
1929  23.9 - (average of the temperatures during 1923-1929)
```

My script is

```
mean=$(awk '{if ($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929) sum += $2; count++} END {print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}' ifile.txt)
awk '{if ($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929) printf "%4i %5.2f\n", $1, $2-'$mean'}' ifile.txt > ofile.txt
```

It is not printing correct values. Would you please check my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach, assuming dates are sorted

```
awk '/1923/,/1929/ {y[++c]=$1; t[c]=$2; sum+=$2} 
     END           {avg=sum/c; 
                    for(k=1;k<=c;k++) print y[k],t[k]-avg}' file

1923 -0.0571429
1924 -0.857143
1925 0.142857
1926 0.842857
1927 -0.657143
1928 0.942857
1929 -0.357143
```

you can fix the print format.

yet, with a double scan it can be further simplified

```
$ awk '/1923/,/1929/{if (NR==FNR) {sum+=$2; c++; avg=sum/c} 
                     else print $1,$2-avg}' file{,}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I understood it. Again, I am facing to find out trend during the same period. Would you please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916647/how-compute-trend-using-awk

Answer (score 1):

@Kay:@try: Though Karakfa's solution is nice. This solution could be used as alternative and don't have any arrays in it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{f=1;if($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){count++;SUM+=$2;};next} FNR==1 && f==1{AVG=SUM/count;next} ($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){print $1, $2-AVG}'  Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT1:** Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
                f=1;
                if($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){
                                                count++;
                                                SUM+=$2;
                                            };
                next
            }
     FNR==1 && f==1{
                AVG=SUM/count;
                next
                   }
     ($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){
                print $1, $2-AVG
            }
    '  Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT2:** Adding explanation for solution too now. Following is for explanation purposes you could run above code only.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{                                               ## Checking condition FNR==NR, which will be only TRUE when first time Input_file is being read. FNR and NR both tells us number of lines of Input_file oinly difference is FNR's value will be RESET whenever a next Input_file is veing read and NR's value will be increasing till all Input_files are read.
                f=1;                                        ## making a variable named f's value to 1.
                if($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){               ## Checking condition if $1(first field's) value is graeter than 1923 and lesser than 1929, then do following operations.
                                                count++;    ## make a variable named count and increment it each time it satisfy the above condition.
                                                SUM+=$2;    ## creating a variable named SUM whose value will be SUM of $2's value and it will add into previous value to get the SUM of all $2's value of all matching lines.
                                            };
                next                                        ## next is built-in keyword which will skip the next statements.
            }
     FNR==1 && f==1{                                        ## Checking conditions if FNR==1 and f==1, which will be TRUE when first Input_file is read and before 1st line of Input_file is being read.
                AVG=SUM/count;                              ## creating a variable named AVG which will have average by dividing the variable SUM and variable named count.
                next                                        ## using next statement to skip all further statements and save a cycle of cpu may be.
                   }
     ($1 >= 1923 && $1 <= 1929){                            ## Checking condition if $1's value is greater than 1923 and lesser or equal to 1929n then perform following actions.
                print $1, $2-AVG                            ## print the value of $1 and then $2-AVG(as per your request).
            }
    ' Input_file  Input_file                                ## Mentioning the Inpur_file 2 times here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by reading same file twice, 1st reading is to calculate average, and second reading is to calculate anomaly, practically reading twice same file can be slow, but  practically zero memory overhead, you will not get error message like `out of memory` as we are not using array here.

**One-liner :**

```
awk -v s="1923" -v e="1929" '{f=$1>=s && $1<=e}f && NR==FNR{sum+=$2; c++; next}f{ print $0, $2-(sum/c) }' file file
```

**Explanation :**

```
awk -v s="1923" -v e="1929" '             # call awk set var s and e
                                          # where s is starting year
                                          # e is ending year
            { 
                f=$1>=s && $1<=e          # f holds boolean status whether data is within a range
            }

f && NR==FNR{                             # if data is within a range
                                          # and we are reading file first time (FNR==NR is true only when awk reads first file), then

               sum+=$2;                   # sum column2 value
               c++;                       # increment counter
               next                       # stop processing go to next line (skipping any code below this line)
            }
                                          # Here we read same file second time
           f{                             # again are we within a range ( f holds boolean status true or false, if true then )
                print $0, $2-(sum/c)      # print current record/line/row, 2nd field minus average
            }' file file
```

**Input :**

```
$ cat file
1921  25
1922  25.1
1923  24.2
1924  23.4
1925  24.4
1926  25.1
1927  23.6
1928  25.2
1929  23.9
1930  25.6
```

**Output :**

```
$ awk -v s="1923" -v e="1929" '{f=$1>=s && $1<=e}f && NR==FNR{sum+=$2; c++; next}f{ print $0, $2-(sum/c) }' file file
1923  24.2 -0.0571429
1924  23.4 -0.857143
1925  24.4 0.142857
1926  25.1 0.842857
1927  23.6 -0.657143
1928  25.2 0.942857
1929  23.9 -0.357143
```

Answer (score 1):

And yet another alternative:

```
awk '/192[3-9]/{a[$1]=$2;sum+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i] - sum/length(a)}' file
```

The for loop does not guarantee order in its current call but you can simply expand it out to the traditional for loop if need be.