# How to compute trend using awk?

Tags: shell, awk, rate, trend

I have a time series of temperature data as:

```
ifile.txt
1921  25
1922  25.1
1923  24.2
1924  23.4
1925  24.4
1926  25.1
1927  23.6
1928  25.2
1929  23.9
1930  25.6
```

I would like to compute the trend for the period 1923-1929.

My algorithm to do it is:

Fit the above points to a line such as

```
Y = mX + c ; where m is the trend
```

I could find the trend for whole period, but I can't able to modify my script when selecting for a specific period. Would you please check my script?

```
awk '/1923/,/1929/ {if (NR==FNR) x[NR] = $1;y[NR] = $2;
      sx += x[NR]; sy += y[NR];
      sxx += x[NR]*x[NR];
      sxy += x[NR]*y[NR];}
      END{
      det = NR*sxx - sx*sx;
      trend = (NR*sxy - sx*sy)/det;
      print trend;}' ifile.txt
```

It is not printing correct value.

```
 The correct value is 0.0679
```

Comment: What is the 'correct' trend for you?

Comment: @dawg : That is actually the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify it little bit, you're not counting the matching records.  `NR` will be total number of lines in the END block.

```
awk '/1923/,/1929/ {sx+=$1; sy+=$2; c++;
                    sxx+=$1*$1; sxy+=$1*$2}
           END     {det=c*sxx-sx*sx;
                    print det?(c*sxy-sx*sy)/det:"DIV0"}' file
```

also need to consider denominator being zero.  The trend comes up as

```
0.0678571
```

Comment: Would it be possible to help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672647/find-linear-trend-up-to-the-maximum-value-using-awk