# Find linear trend up to the maximum value using awk

Tags: shell, awk, trendline

I have a datafile as below:

ifile.txt

```
-10     /
-9      /
-8      /
-7      3
-6      4
-5      13
-4      16
-3      17
-2      23
-1      26
0       29
1       32
2       35
3       38
4       41
5       40
6       35
7       30
8       25
9       /
10      /
```

Here "/" are the missing values. I would like to compute the linear trend up to the maximum value in the y-axis (i.e. up to the value "41" in 2nd column). So it should calculate the trend from the following data:

```
-7      3
-6      4
-5      13
-4      16
-3      17
-2      23
-1      26
0       29
1       32
2       35
3       38
4       41
```

Other (x, y) won't be consider because the y values are less than 41 after (4, 41)

The following script is working fine for all values:

```
awk '!/\//{sx+=$1; sy+=$2; c++;
                    sxx+=$1*$1; sxy+=$1*$2}
           END     {det=c*sxx-sx*sx;
                    print (det?(c*sxy-sx*sy)/det:"DIV0")}' ifile.txt
```

But I can't able to do it for maximum value

```
For the given example the result will be 3.486
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on your comments. I assumed your trend calculations were good and used them:

```
$ awk '
$2!="/" {
    b1[++j]=$1                            # buffer them up until or if used
    b2[j]=$2
    if(max=="" || $2>max) {               # once a bigger than current max found
        max=$2                            # new champion
        for(i=1;i<=j;i++) {               # use all so far buffered values
            # print  b1[i], b2[i]         # debug to see values used
            sx+=b1[i]                     # Your code from here on
            sy+=b2[i]
            c++
            sxx+=b1[i]*b1[i]
            sxy+=b1[i]*b2[i]
        }
        j=0                               # buffer reset
        delete b1
        delete b2
    }
}
END {
    det=c*sxx-sx*sx
    print (det?(c*sxy-sx*sy)/det:"DIV0")
}' file
```

For data:

```
0       /
1       1
2       2
3       4
4       3
5       5
6       10
7       7
8       8
```

with debug `print` uncommented program would output:

```
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 3
5 5
6 10
1.51429
```

Comment: It seems this script is considering all the y values less than 41. But I am looking for the trend until the maximum y. The (x , y) values beyond the maximum y should not come into the account. Thank you very much. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Kay It accepts all increasing values of _y_, for example from set `(1,2,4,3,5)` it would use `(1,2,4,5)` so in your example it would take the values up to 41.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for trend of all entries up to the maximum y. From your example, lets say for y, from the set (1,2,4,3,5), it should consider all (1,2,4,3,5), as 5 is maximum. Similarly for the set (1,2,4,3,5,4,3), it should consider (1,2,4,3,5), as maximum is 5, so the numbers after 5 i.e. 4 & 3 won't come into account. Another example could be like, from the set (1,2,4,3,5,10,7,8), it would consider (1,2,4,3,5,10)`, it should not consider 7 and 8, as they are coming after 10.

Comment: Updated based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the update of the concerned rows only when `$2 > max` and save the intermediate rows into variables. for example using associate arrays:

```
awk '
  $2 == "/" {next}
  $2 > max {
    # update max if $2 > max
    max = $2;
    # add all elemenet of a1 to a and b1 to b
    for (k in a1) {
      a[k] = a1[k]; b[k] = b1[k]
    }
    # add the current row to a, b
    a[NR] = $1; b[NR] = $2; 
    # reset a1, b1
    delete a1; delete b1;
    next;
  }
  # if $2 <= max, then set a1, b1
  { a1[NR] = $1; b1[NR] = $2 }
  END{
    for (k in a) {
      #print k, a[k], b[k]
      sx += a[k]; sy += b[k]; sxx += a[k]*a[k]; sxy += a[k]*b[k]; c++
    }
    det=c*sxx-sx*sx;
    print (det?(c*sxy-sx*sy)/det:"DIV0")
  }
' ifile.txt
#3.48601
```

Or calculate sx, sy etc directly instead of using arrays:

```
awk '
  $2 == "/" {next}
  $2 > max {
    # update max if $2 > max
    max = $2;
    # add the current Row plus the cached values
    sx += $1+sx1; sy += $2+sy1; sxx += $1*$1+sxx1; sxy += $1*$2+sxy1; c += 1+c1
    # reset the cached variables
    sx1 = 0; sy1 = 0; sxx1 = 0; sxy1 = 0; c1 = 0;
    next;
  }
  # if $2 <= max, then calculate and cache the values
  { sx1 += $1; sy1 += $2; sxx1 += $1*$1; sxy1 += $1*$2; c1++ }
  END{
    det=c*sxx-sx*sx;
    print (det?(c*sxy-sx*sy)/det:"DIV0")
  }
' ifile.txt
```

Comment: Yes. It worked perfectly fine. Many thanks. The bounty is yours now. It will take another 20 hours to get this.

Comment: just curious, is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine. I was just distributing the credit. I promised to give you the bounty. Sorry for the inconvenience.